# Q: How to retrieve date with time(hours,minutes,seconds) from a 19 digit number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, to-date

I want to get date and time from a 19 digit number in Oracle and could not find any solution for this big numbers. The time should be in the format HH24:MI:SS. I am able to retrieve the date but unable to get the time.

**Example Numbers to get the date and time:

```
1190205161950369000 , 1190206092859146000 , 1181230172734928000 , 1181108121251823000
```

For this numbers above, I added them an addition value "19000000000000000000" and substring first 8 digits from the total value so that the first 8 digits give me the date(yyyymmdd).

**For Example :**

SUBSTR(1190205161950369000+19000000000000000000,0,8) = 20190205

Hence, the date is 05-02-2019(DD-MM-YYYY). But to get the time, even if I increase the substring length from 8 to 14 or 18 still I only get date and not time.

SQL Query Used :

```
Select to_date(SUBSTR(1190205161950369000+19000000000000000000,0,8),
    'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') as truedate
from dual;
```

Result:

```
TRUEDATE
---------
05-02-2019
```

I have also tried this but does not work :

```
Select to_date(SUBSTR(1190205161950369000+19000000000000000000,0,14),
    'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS.SSSSS') as truedate
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, to convert the value, this seems to work:

```
select to_date(substr(to_char(1190205161950369000 + 19000000000000000000), 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
from dual
```

By default dates don't show the times.  You can convert to a string or you can convert to a timestamp instead:

```
select to_timestamp(substr(to_char(1190205161950369000 + 19000000000000000000), 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
from dual;
```

You can see that the time component is there by converting the `date` to a `timestamp`:

```
select to_timestamp(to_date(substr(to_char(1190205161950369000 + 19000000000000000000), 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))
from dual
```

Comment: Thanks. The second query converting it to timestamp works but the seconds contain too many fractions. When I run this query the output is :
05-02-19 16:19:50,000000000

Comment: @DhaneshAgrawal . . . The time is there, you just can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the time portion contains fractional seconds consisting of six digits. You can convert it like so:

```
WITH tests AS (
   SELECT 1190205161950369000 AS n FROM DUAL UNION
   SELECT 1190206092859146000 FROM DUAL UNION 
   SELECT 1181230172734928000 FROM DUAL UNION 
   SELECT 1181108121251823000 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT n, TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(n + 19000000000000000000), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF')
FROM tests
```

Comment: Thanks Salman. Yes it seems to have microseconds which I do not want to show :(

Comment: You can use Gordon's answer (1st one). The date will contain hour, minute and seconds. If necessary call the to_char again to format the date as desired (`to_char(to_date(substr(to_char..., 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`)